# EF4 CTP5 - HasColumnType not working

Tags: entity-framework-4, ef4-code-only, entity-framework-ctp5

I want to override the default nvarchar(4000) for one of my string columns to a text data type in SQL Express. I use this code.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Accommodation>()
               .Property(p => p.Information)
               .HasColumnType("text");
```

But the column type remains as nvarchar?

I also asked here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adonetefx/thread/a1d84ea9-2f8e-42f0-bb83-ac9f68805d6d?prof=required

Comment: You should consider using _nvarchar(max)_ instead of _text_. Microsoft is keeping the text datatype in SQL Server 2005 and 2008 for backwards compatibility, but they encourage you to use the new nvarchar(max) datatype. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178158(v=SQL.100).aspx)

Comment: Excellent point I have changed my code to HasColumnType("varchar(max)");  and it works fine. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh I just figured it out, adding the fluent mapping was not sufficient to force the table to dropAndCreate itself again even though I had DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges set.

I had to force it to update the table manually.